# Matplotlib Plot time series with colored points Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, timeserieschart

I'm trying to plot time series data where there are multiple points at each time. I want to have `time`on the x axis, `Amount` on the y axis and then color each point by ID i.e. where `ID = 344` they would all have the same color etc.

Below is example data i'm using. I'm sure this must exist but I can't find gallery examples on Matplotlib.org

```
                ID     Amount
Time                        
2015-12-09      344    0.333333
2015-12-10      345    0.333333
2015-12-09      345    0.333333
2015-12-09      344    0.750000
2015-12-09      342    0.583333
```

Things i've tried include trying to reshape the data as a pivot table (didn't work because there are two duplicate values for `ID 344`. Groupby, but I've struggled grouping by two columns, I think if I could groupby ID and retain the Time field this would go some way towards solving my problem.

Any help or advice would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the docs and look at examples for scatter within pylab or matplotlib

```
import pylab as pl

fig= pl.figure( figsize=(5,5) )
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(df.index, df.Amount, s=20, c=df.ID)
```

This can be customized to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, do you know if it's possible to use time stamp data for the x axis in a scatter plot?

Comment: It is, but it must first be converted from string to datetime.